# Bonded neutral generator - connecting to house and removing bond in main panel instead of within generator

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, generator, grounding-and-bonding

When connecting a generator to a house, since it's a bonded neutral generator, I was told that I need to first remove the bond within the generator since there's already a house bond.

I was going to do this but when opening up the generator and seeing it was very hard to get to this, an electrician told me that it'd just be easier to remove the bond at the house when this is needed by removing what is shown below with the blue arrow (seen in the main panel)).  Is this an okay route to go?

Btw, the generator is being connected through an inlet and there is an interlock to prevent backfeeding.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that you will forget to do this and have problems, or forget to put it back when switching back to utility power and have problems. The nice thing about an interlock is things only work if you use it. But things will *seem* to work if you forget to unbond or bond the ground/neutral, so you won't realize you have a problem until it becomes a **Problem**.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the interlock I have is just to prevent the mains breaker being able to be on at the same time as the inlet breaker. If I make sure I remember to restore the home bond when done, would the approach I'm inquiring about be good?

Comment: Your panel doesn't have any ground bars. It has neutral bars on both sides.  (notice how both rails are insulated).  It was sold without ground bars pre-installed, but the sites are pre-drilled and tapped for accessory ground bars you can buy.   That strap is a permanent part of the panel that bonds the neutral bars on both sides.  The neutral-ground bond is somewhere else.  Possibly a green screw or a hook.  But your plan won't work, don't do it.

Comment: I am making a comparison between the interlock and the bonding. The interlock is so that you *can't* use the generator without cutting off utility power, and vice versa. But your scheme for the neutral/ground bonding makes is so that you *could* easily (i.e., no deliberate action/inaction or anything broken, just simply forgetting a step) end up in a dangerous situation.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine I've uploaded a better front-on view and it appears there are ground wires running into the left bar - does that change anything or do you have any other thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @g491 -- what make/model is your generator? Also, is there a specific reason (aside from cost) that you want to use an interlock on your main panel, instead of breaking your standby loads out into a subpanel?

Comment: No, it's still a neutral bar. This is a 32-*space* 64-*circuit* panel. It can accommodate 64 circuits using thin breakers.  Thus it needs 64 neutrals.  Each bar has 32-33 spots so **you need them all for neutral**.  Fully populating this panel will require accessory ground bars to put the grounds on. The dingbat idea of using 1 bar for ground only works because the panel is lightly filled with only 18 circuits.  ....... However, I notice the screws that hold that bar are green, so maybe it is intended to be "convertible" (usable either way).  How is it the 240V breakers add up to 370A?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's a Sportsman GEN85KIDF.  The majority of the standby loads (but not all), are on a 100A subpanel which lives in the garage and is run off of this main 200A panel (that's what's in the lower right of the second pic), so if doing an additional subpanel by the inlet, it'd need to feed that plus some of the stuff on the main one. Thanks

Comment: @g491 yeah, having a subpanel feeding another subpanel isn't an issue (it happens all the time in big buildings, which may have subpanels nested 3, 4, 5 deep if you will)

Answer (score 5):

### You can't use an interlock with a bonded neutral generator

Since you need that main panel bond to be there in order to have a solid neutral-ground bond while on utility power (NEC 250.24(B)), you can't use your interlock kit with your current generator.  So, you'll either have to get a switching neutral transfer panel (Eaton CHGEN...SN or Reliance Panel/Link X series), do the surgery to unbond your generator no matter how arduous it'd be, or return your generator and buy a different generator with a floating neutral.

Comment: So removing the home bond so there's only one bond (i.e. in the generator) wouldn't be proper? It seemed to make sense when the electrician told me it was good but I don't claim expertise in this area. Thanks

Comment: @g491 it would be terrible. If your range ever had an element contact ground, you'd have 1-5kA of fault current trying to make it from ground to neutral. WIth the panel bond gone, it would run out the #10? ground wire out to the generator, through the gen's N-G bond, and back the #8? neutral wire to the panel.  The high resistance of these small wires would limit current, preventing an instant breaker trip. Or it could burn out a wire and then you'd have no N-G bond *at all*, and that is "interesting", I had that happen once.

Comment: Also removing that bond may be a pain, but if you only plan to use this generator as home utility power backup then it is a one-time pain and *done*. If you plan to use this is a temporary job-site generator *and* as a home backup then that's a different story.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine The cable being used is STW 6/3 + 8/1 (Conntek model TES1450-20 50A) - would that still pose the same concern that you shared for #8 + #10? Sorry if the answer is obvious. Thanks

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Yes, unfortunately I'd like to be able to use it for both.  I had hoped the bond would be easier to access.

Comment: Then you would be better off looking for a generator that is easier to bond/unbond.

Comment: @g491 I was referring to that current path when the house is on utility, but you haven't reinstalled the N-G bond and are still relying on the one on the generator.  Anyway when the generator is off on an adventure, the neutral-ground bond would be GONE.  You swear you'll put it back in the panel, but what if you didn't?   Honestly, the least bad way to violate code would be to break the ground pin off the generator cable.  Can't belive I'm saying that.

Comment: OK.  I'll ask the stupid question: Why can't the OP leave both bonds in place?  I can see why removing the house bond is bad (particularly if the generator can go off to act as a site genny), but why is leaving both in place bad?

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica because you'd wind up with stray currents flowing on the generator grounding system and chassis (at the very least, any time you had a ground fault in the house)

Comment: @g491 _you_ might remember to connect/disconnect the neutral/gound bond in the panel every time you fire up the generator, but how about the next person? How about if you're traveling and your SO, kids, housemates need to do it? There are just too many ways _I pinky-swear I'll remember to do it every time_ can go wrong.

Comment: In a modern setup with an outside disconnect switch the neutral is bonded there and not in the panel. If the first step in switching to generator power is to switch that OFF, does that disconnect the neutral as well as the hots? Then is the neutral bond still in  place on the house side of that switch? There where does the generator connect to the house wiring? A friend has a large connector on the outside wall by the disconnect and an interlock inside in the panel I suppose backfed through some breaker which is connected through an interlock. Generator have floating or bonded neutral?

Comment: @JimStewart -- you're probably better off breaking out those to questions of their own, or at the very least the second one

Answer (score 1):

You could make a short adapter cable to put between the cable from the generator output and the house inlet, that connects hot(s) and neutral but not ground.  Then you will be using the house ground which is a better ground than the generator will have anyway.  The neutral to ground bonding in the generator is for when you are using it to power loads directly so it can provide some semblance of ground and hopefully detect faults. But when you connect it to the house, there should be only one place where ground and neutral are bonded, and the house will have a much beefier ground. As a plus you won't damage either the generator or the house, or create a dangerous situation where you don't have a good ground in case of a fault. Just avoid putting the generator where it has a good earth ground.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea (though I don't claim any electrical expertise) - would it make sense to just remove the ground pin from one end of the existing cable I have if this is all it will be used for?

Comment: I think that should work, but if you ever hook up a floating generator (one with neutral not connected to ground) you should probably get a proper cable with ground connected so a ground fault at the generator would be detected.

Answer (score 0):

Find the neutral wire that connects to ground on the generator and put an on off switch by the outlet used to power the transfer switch

Comment: Are you suggesting that since it's too hard to get to where neutral connects to ground on the generator maybe I locate the neutral elsewhere and add an on/off switch inline to it? Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).